# How to add an option menu item?

Tags: android

I'm totally new in android and I'm doing an app that change the background color when I press a button. I have already done that but now I want to add a menu item which will start the mode with or without buttons.

I was trying to do this but I don't know if I'm doing good.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Hidden").
            setPositiveButton("OK", null).
            create().
            show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }
    }
```

and XML

```
 <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Hidden"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Visible"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_exit"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="Cancel"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: You have 2 menu items with the same id... I guess it's a typo?

Comment: I have changed the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First edit menu items id:
 from `android:id="@+id/action_settings"` to `android:id="@+id/action_hidden"`;
 from `android:id="@+id/action_settings"` to `android:id="@+id/action_visible"`;
from `android:id="@+id/action_exit"` to `android:id="@+id/action_cancel"`;
XML file:

```
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_hidden"
            android:title="Hidden"/>    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_visible"
            android:title="Visible"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
            android:title="Cancel"/>
    </menu>
```

Then use this:

```
         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.YOUR_ACTIVITY!!!!, menu);
           return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {    
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_hidden:
                //code for action_hidden
                return true;

            case R.id.action_visible:
                //code for action_visible
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_cancel:
                //code for menu_cancel   
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @jaimito did you change menu_items id in menu.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did, as you have said

Comment: it says, the application has stopped unexpectly. I can't run the app :/

Comment: @jaimito answer updated. try now, but change YOUR_ACTIVITY!!!! to your ativity name

Comment: Yeah now I don't have any errors and I can run my app but it didn't show up the new window

Comment: @jaimito press Menu button on your phone (button in left down corner)

Comment: I don't have a device but I hace try with the virtual one and works! Thanks!!